# Mapping nested member by id

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Assume I have a User object - can be fetched via /api/users/:id

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 26,
    "computer": 1
}
```

The computer property describes the type of the computer he owns - can be fetched
via /api/computers - returns array of computer types. I map this object to the Computer object

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "name" : "stationary"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "laptop"
}]
```

Is there any way I can tell RestKit to automatically map the Computer object by the ID in the result? i.e when I GET the user from RestKit, RestKit will automatically initiate a new GET (behind the scene) in order to get the real Computer object from the server (rather than just represent it as an ID)

i.e

```
User *someUser = ...; // GET with restkit
someUser.computer = ...; // a Computer object with properties .name and .id
```

**EDIT**

This is available while using Core Data as seen [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#connecting-non-nested-relationships-using-foreign-keys). It is unclear whether one can achieve the same without using core data..

Answer (score 0):

The link you refer to is for existing connecting objects to new objects in a response, not triggering a GET request as a result of new object creation.

Triggering the GET is not a provided feature of RestKit so you need to implement that logic yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know.. ended up implementing it myself. Thanks for your answer!